# when do there exist proper endomorphisms of field extensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Is there a simple characterization of field extensions $F\subset K$ for which there exists a *proper* endomorphism (i.e. not surjective), $K\rightarrow K$, fixing $F$ pointwise?

If $K/F$ is algebraic, then no such exists (right?). So I expect the condition to be something about transcendence.

Comment: Do you have any examples at all to refer to?

Comment: @Lubin The forbenius endomorphism for the field of rational functions F_p(t) over F_p works right?  There the role of the transcendental t is clear

Comment: Yes (for number fields), because for any finite field extension K/F, every element of K is the root of a polynomial of F[x] of finite degree which has finitely many roots. If two elements coincide in the image, they must both be roots of the same polynomial (I.E conjugates). Hence the kernel is finite so it must be 0. Invective implies surjective for finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @TCiur right, thanks for confirming

Answer (score 3):

Sure, here are the most basic examples: let $F$ be any field, and let $K$ be a simple transcendental extension, $K=F(t)$. Now, let $g=g(t)$ be any nonconstant element of $K$, thus a rational function with coefficients from $F$. Certainly $g$ is also transcendental over $F$, and we may define $\psi:K\to F(g)\subset K$ by sending $t$ to $g$.

More explicitly, if $f\in F(t)$, let $\psi(f)=f\circ g$. Even more explicitly yet, if $f$ is a polynomial, say $f=\sum_ia_it^i$, then $\psi(f)=f(g(t))=\sum_ia_i(g(t))^i$. And extend $\psi:F[t]\to K$ to the fraction-field in the obvious way. Notice that constants are left fixed by $\psi$.

Simplest example, if $g(t)=t^2$, then $f(t)\mapsto f(t^2)$.

In every case, $[K:\psi(K)]$ is equal to the *degree* of $g$, where this is just the ordinary degree of $g$ if $g$ is a polynomial, and the max of the degree of the denominator and the degree of the numerator if $g$ is a rational function that’s not a polynomial. ( Of course $g$ must be reduced to lowest terms! )

Comment: Thanks, so obviously my field theory is a bit rusty.  So you want to first insert the algebraic closure $\overline{F}_K$ of $F$ in $K$, so that we get $F\subset \overline{F}_K\subset K$, where the second extension is purely transcendental. And then you can freely construct your endomorphism (by assigning values to generators of $K$ over $\overline{F}_K$)  all while fixing $\overline{F}_K$.  Is that right?

Comment: That was not what I was saying at all. I was *constructing* a simple purely transcendental extension, $K=F(t)$. Here, $F$ is its own algebraic closure in $K$. The transcendence degree is $1$, so that there is only one generator to evaluate.

Comment: Right, I was trying to turn what you said into a proof that every transcendental extension admits a proper endomorphism (since I asked for a *characterization* of such extensions).  I think that works, but please let me know if there's something wrong with what I said.

Comment: It’s not clear to me that it’s the case for fields like $\Bbb R$ that have no automorphisms beyond the identity. But thinking about such things gives me a bit of a headache.

Comment: huh, good point. i guess my thinking has been naive -- I thought that if you had a purely transcendental extension, you could send your transcendence basis anywhere you want.  But evidently not. hmm

Comment: Well, you can send the transcendence basis to any algebraically independent set of the same cardinality, that’s not a problem. The problem is extending the final algebraic extension *within your original field*. Don’t hesitate to e-mail me if you’d like to discuss all of this a bit further.